# Unable to find ancestors using recursion

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am having trouble getting the "grandparent" of a child.

```
//main class
User finalAlternate = new User();
        for(User user: userList) {
            if(user.getAlternateContactId() != null) {
                finalAlternate = checkAlternate(user);
                approverMap.put(finalAlternate.getId(), user.getId());
            }
        }

//helper method
public User checkAlternate(User user) { //returns the alternate
        User alternateUser = new User();
        if(user.getAlternateContactId() != null) {
            alternateUser = userMQService.getUser(user.getAlternateContactId(), new UserCollection[]{UserCollection.ROLES, UserCollection.GROUPS});
        } else {
            return user;
        }
        return checkAlternate(alternateUser);

    }
```

I have a collection of Users that look something like:

```
User A -> User B -> User C
```

All these Users are related with each other due to their alternate contact Id. So User A's alternateContactId is the Id of User B and User B's alternateContacId is the ID of User C. When I run my method my map's result looks something like this:

```
 User C -> User B
```

So, how would I fix my method so that the map looks like this:

```
User C -> User A
```

Basically how can I fix my method so I can get the first ancestor of any child?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You store the Users you have created inside a hashMap and give each user a unique identifier, i chose to use an integer that increases by 1 each time it's used.

Here is a sample implementation just to get you started:

```
public class User {

    private static final HashMap<Integer, User> hashMap = new HashMap();
    private static int index = 0;
    private static int NO_PARENT = -1;

    public final String name;
    public final int id;
    public final int parentId;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = ++index;
        this.parentId = NO_PARENT;
        hashMap.put(id, this);
    }

    public User(String name, int parentId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = ++index;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        hashMap.put(id, this);
    }

    private User getGrandParent(User u, int generation) {
        if (generation == 2)
            return u;
        if (u != null && u.parentId != NO_PARENT)
            return getGrandParent(hashMap.get(u.parentId), generation +1);
        return null;
    }

    public User getGrandParen() {
        return getGrandParent(this, 0);
    }
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User u1 = new User("A");
    User u2 = new User("B", u1.id);
    User u3 = new User("C", u2.id);
    User u4 = new User("D", u3.id);
    System.out.println("grandparent of C is: " + u3.getGrandParen().name);
    System.out.println("grandparent of D is: " + u4.getGrandParen().name);
}
```

Output:

```
grandparent of C is: A
grandparent of D is: B
```

Note that you would have to flush the HashMap of Users that you no longer need.

It wasn't clear to me what your userMQService did, if it's asynchronous task it's a whole nother ball game but you specificed HashMap and array so I assumed you wanted something like this.

To get the first ancestor you do:

```
private User getFirstAncestor(User u) {
    if (u != null && u.parentId != NO_PARENT)
        return getFirstAncestor(hashMap.get(u.parentId));
    return u;
}

public User getFirstAncestor() {
    if (parentId == NO_PARENT) 
        return null; // there is no ancestry.
    return getFirstAncestor(this);
}
```

Here is another example that doesn't modify the User class:'

```
public class UserAncestry {
private static final HashMap<User, User> mapParent = new HashMap<>();

public static void setParent(User child, User parent) {
    mapParent.put(child, parent);
}

public static User getParent(User user) {
    return mapParent.get(user);
}

public static User getFirstAncenstor(User user) {
    User parent = mapParent.get(user);
    if (parent != null)
        return getFirstAncenstor(parent);
    return user;
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User u1 = new User("A");
    User u2 = new User("B");
    User u3 = new User("C");
    User u4 = new User("D");
    UserAncestry.setParent(u2, u1);
    UserAncestry.setParent(u3, u2);
    UserAncestry.setParent(u4, u3);
    User uu1 = UserAncestry.getFirstAncenstor(u4);
    User uu2 = UserAncestry.getFirstAncenstor(u3);
    System.out.println("uu1:: " + uu1.name);
    System.out.println("uu1:: " + uu2.name);
}
```

Comment: How would I get A as a parent from D, I was more kinda wondering on how I would be able to get the very first first ancestor, rather than the grandparent. Would it follow the same kind of logic? Is there a way to keep track of the parent/children relationship?

Comment: Oh thats simple, just remove the part that is counting the generations. Added it to my answer.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry.

Comment: The if-statement to check if generation is equal to 2 is what determines something to be a grandparent, if you remove that it won't break and keep going backwards until it reaches the end.

Comment: Ahh right. Duh. Thanks. I am gonna try to make it work with the stuff that I have right now. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, what if adding parentId wasnt possible. I am working with really large codebase and adding parentId isnt really possible. Is there a way I could keep track of the parents without parentId?

Comment: You can instead store the parent as a node rather than using a hashMap? But you are already using alternateContactId which should be equivalent to what i called parentId. So you'd just change the static increment to your own using alternateContactId as a key - the principle is the same.

Comment: I added an example that doesn't modify the User-class, however you need to configure the parent somehow (look above).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overwriting previous entries in the `Child/GrandParent` map. For example.

```
User finalAlternate = new User();
for(User user: userList) {
    if(user.getAlternateContactId() != null) {
        // Assuming the users are in the following order in the list [A, B, C]
        // In the first iteration you pass A
        finalAlternate = checkAlternate(user); 
        // checkAlternate(A) will traverse A->B->C until it finds C, so when
        // this method returns, finalAlternate should be equal to C.
        // All good! that is what we wanted

        // After the first iteration we have approveMap.put(C, A);
        approverMap.put(finalAlternate.getId(), user.getId());
    }
}
```

In the second iteration

```
for(User user: userList) {
    if(user.getAlternateContactId() != null) {
        // In the second iteration you pass B
        finalAlternate = checkAlternate(user); 
        // checkAlternate(B) will traverse B->C until it finds C, so when
        // this method returns, finalAlternate should be equal to C.


        // After the second iteration we have approveMap.put(C, B); // here is the problem
        approverMap.put(finalAlternate.getId(), user.getId());
    }
}
```

If and only if, your list is sorted in such a way that grandparents occur before parents  then a simple check for [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) should do the trick:

```
if(!approveMap.containsKey(finalAlternate.getId()) {
    approverMap.put(finalAlternate.getId(), user.getId());
}
```

However I don't know if this will help you much since in the list a grandparent might show up after a parent for example `[B, A, C]` will give you the "correct" output. To address this issue, you can add a `parent` field to each `User` and then you can check whether or not that `User` is a grandparent by setting the `parent` of each grandparent `User` to `null`:

```
public class User {

    private User parent = null; // all grandparent users should have parent = null;

    // .. some good code

    public boolean isGrandparent() {
        return parent == null;
    }
}
```

Then you can add that comparison

```
if(user.isGrandparent()) {
    approverMap.put(finalAlternate.getId(), user.getId());
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks. That helps a lot. Another question I had: What happens when A -> B->C and D -> C the map seems to be overriding A -> C so swapping the key and value should be sufficient I believe right?

Comment: @smarty_pants yep D->C will overwrite A->C. Swapping the key and value might get you in the same problem but in reverse order say you store C<-A then C<-D will overwrite the previous entry. One hackish way you might be able to get it to work is to swap key and value like you said and use a `MultiMap` i.e. `Map<K, List<V>>` this way you can have multiple values for the same key. So you will just keep adding all the parents/grandparents for a `key` and once you are done traversing `userList` you just purge those that aren't real "grandparents" from the map. A Tree might be a better fit here.